# Full height section and centering a div in a browser

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to center a div within full height section in a browser window which works on Chrome and Firefox. It doesn't center correctly in Safari on a Mac and Safari / Chrome on an Tablet iPad. Can't see what I've missed.

Here is a link to the site: http://dev.whydidibother.com/osteria/2_2_2015/

My css:

```
.welcome-note {
background: #ffffff;
width: 100%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
min-height: 100vh;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
}
.welcome-text {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
padding: 20px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
padding: 60px !important;
color: #fff;
width: 75%;
}
```

Any ideas folks?

Comment: don't use margin-right.......

Comment: tried removing that but it still doesn't center as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the table method to achieve that vertical alignment effect. I don't recommend using `transform`. Basically you need to create 3 `div`s one with `display:table;` and a child table with display:table-cell and then a third one to hold your text as follows.

```
<div id="vcenter">
    <div id="holder">
        <div id="content">
            <h3>Welcome to Osteria</h3>
            <p>Osteria is an award winning fine dining restaurant in the heart of North Berwick. With several awards under our belts we want to keep the standard up and hope for more. We are a small family restaurant cooking traditional Italian dishes for the Scottish market.</p>  
            <br/><p>Looking forward to seeing you very soon!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#vcenter {
    background-color: #fdface;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
    visibility: visible;
    display: table;   
}

#holder {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
    min-height: 60px;
    visibility: visible;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    text-align:center
}

#content{
    width: 75%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    padding: 40px; 
    margin:0 auto;
    color: #fff;
}
```

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/baksdtuz/3/) is a demo**

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and it does make the #content div centered but it forces the overall container div to the top of the page rather than being in the correct location. It also doesn't make the section fit the browser window height wise.

Comment: managed to get it working with this:

.welcome-note {
 background-color: #fdface;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: visible;
    visibility: visible;
    display: table;
    position: relative;
}
.welcome-text {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
    min-height: 60px;
    visibility: visible;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    text-align:center
    position: absolute;
}
.welcome-container {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 padding: 60px;
 color: #fff;
}

Comment: Ofcourse my example didn't consider other css rules in your website :) I was just trying to give you the idea of how to achieve the desired effect you were asking for. I'm glad it helped :)